# Strong no loop conjecture for uniserial modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a an Artin algebra. The strong no loop conjecture states that a simple $A$-module with $Ext_A^1(S,S) \neq 0$ has infinite projective dimension.
This conjecture was recently proved for quiver algebras and thus finite dimensional algebras over an algebraically closed field in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811002714 .

> Question: Does a uniserial $A$-module $M$ with $Ext_A^1(M,M) \neq 0$ have infinite projective dimension?

Recall here that a module is called uniserial in case it has a unique composition series.

Comment: Isn't a two dimensional indecomposable representation of the Kronecker quiver a counterexample?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes you are right. I tested it for Nakayama algebras and there it seems to be correct. Maybe one needs an additional assumption on $M$ (or better generalisation of being simple) in order to make the question more interesting.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I think the middle term in a short exact sequence for the Kronecker example with 2-dimensional modules is not uniserial. Maybe a better condition is $M$ being uniserial with $Ext_A^1(M,M) \neq 0$ and the existence of a uniserial middle term? But of course you may post your counterexample as an answer. I need to do more tests to find a possible better question.